# Mongodb merge chunk with $maxkey value on sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb

I have shardkey {thread_id:1,_id:1} on collection "post",
and i want to merge 2 following chunk :

```
{
    "_id" : "forum.post-thread_id_\"547dc7c2de2cf22b688b4572\"_id_ObjectId('549c519660e24b65118b456c')",
    "lastmod" : Timestamp(3012, 3),
    "lastmodEpoch" : ObjectId("50829c0e172de38a3398f72c"),
    "ns" : "forum.post",
    "min" : {
        "thread_id" : "547dc7c2de2cf22b688b4572",
        "_id" : ObjectId("549c519660e24b65118b456c")
    },
    "max" : {
        "thread_id" : ObjectId("50901d4e1dd7198161000063"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("50901d4e1dd7198161000068")
    },
    "shard" : "shard3"
}
{
    "_id" : "forum.post-thread_id_ObjectId('50901d4e1dd7198161000063')_id_ObjectId('50901d4e1dd7198161000068')",
    "lastmod" : Timestamp(604, 0),
    "lastmodEpoch" : ObjectId("50829c0e172de38a3398f72c"),
    "ns" : "forum.post",
    "min" : {
        "thread_id" : ObjectId("50901d4e1dd7198161000063"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("50901d4e1dd7198161000068")
    },
    "max" : {
        "thread_id" : {
            "$maxKey" : 1
        },
        "_id" : {
            "$maxKey" : 1
        }
    },
    "shard" : "shard3"
}
```

It need to merge because thread_id supposed to be string , with current condition 1st chunk hold all new data (string -> ObjectId()), and 2nd chunk only hold documents with thread_id "ObjectId()"

I have tried this command :

[reference](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/)

```
db.runCommand({
    mergeChunks : 'forum.post',
    bounds : [{
            thread_id : "547dc7c2de2cf22b688b4572",
            _id : ObjectId("549c519660e24b65118b456c")
        }, {
            thread_id : {
                $type : 127
            },
            _id : {
                $type : 127
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

And i got this error :

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "shard key bounds [{
          thread_id: " 547dc7c2de2cf22b688b4572 ", 
          _id: ObjectId(" 549c519660e24b65118b456c ") 
    },{ 
          thread_id: { $type: 127 }, _id: { $type: 127 } })
          are not valid for shard key pattern { thread_id: 1.0, _id: 1.0 }"
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Mongodb Version 2.4.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear that "mergechunk" command was on later version 2.6.x ++

I solved my problem using this command :

```
db.runCommand({
    mergeChunks : 'forum.post',
    bounds : [{
            thread_id : "547dc7c2de2cf22b688b4572",
            _id : ObjectId("549c519660e24b65118b456c")
        }, {
            thread_id : MaxKey,
            _id : MaxKey
        }
    ]
})
```

it appear that for "write" we should use :

`db.foo.insert({ id : MaxKey });`

For "Query" we should use :

`db.foo.find({ id : { $type : 127 } });`